# PHP return nothing from Android Post values

Tags: php, android

i am using web service to send user information to **MySQL** but  **PHP** doesn't return posted values  when i am trying to echo the values, and gives me:

```
Notice: Undefined index: user_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\sign_up.php on line 5
```

my code :

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/webservice/sign_up.php");
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> post = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            post.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name", name));
            post.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_email", email));
            post.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_password", password));
            request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(post));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();  
            Log.i("data posted, status = " , Integer.toString(status)); 

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        }  

        return null;


    }
}
```

and **PHP** :

```
<?php
$user = $_POST["user_name"];
echo $user;
?>
```

Comment: `print_r($_POST); `what does it show?

Comment: recurrent problem it seems. We had the same question a few days ago.

Comment: It clearly says: `Notice: Undefined index: user_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\sign_up.php on line 5`

Comment: show var_dump($_POST); if possible

Comment: i used  print_r($_POST); it gives me :  Array()

Comment: and var_dump($_POST); gives me array(0) { }

Comment: any other suggestions? @Harikrishnan ,@dumazy

Comment: It means no data is getting Posted to your php file...Check webserver access/error logs for more info.

Comment: in access_log : 
"POST /webservice/sign_up.php HTTP/1.1" 200 140 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"
"GET /webservice/sign_up.php HTTP/1.1" 200 13 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36" @Harikrishnan

Comment: seems fine for me...Try this http://adilmukarram.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/sending-and-receiving-data-from-a-php-web-application/

Comment: i tried it but it gave me the same result! @Harikrishnan

Comment: @justfemale great!...I'm glad to hear that...I have posted it as answer please accept that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code to pass string from android client to PHP

**Android Client part**

The code below will enable your android app to talk to a webpage.

Note : You also need to enable uses permission for internet in the android.manifest file.

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Code for android app

```
public void postData(String toPost) {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.URL.com/yourpage.php");

//This is the data to send
String MyName = 'adil'; //any data to send

try {
// Add your data
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", MyName));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

// Execute HTTP Post Request

ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

//This is the response from a php application
String reverseString = response;
Toast.makeText(this, "response" + reverseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
Toast.makeText(this, "CPE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
Toast.makeText(this, "IOE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
}

}//end postData()
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php

echo $_POST["action"];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do one of the following:

- print_r($_POST);
- Use a program like fiddler to capture traffic, and see if you POST request is being sent

Comment: print_r($_POST);  gives me : Array()

Comment: and i used fiddler, the request doesn't return anything

Comment: anything else? @Aaron